# Yielding unique values from a list python

Tags: python, duplicates, yield

i need to yield unique elements for example if i have the list [3,4,5,7,3,9,0,3], i would only yield 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 0.

```
def unique(sequence):
    for i in sequence:
        yield (i) 
    return sequence
```

I will not iterate

Comment: `for i in set(sequence)`

Comment: it changes the order of the remaining elements.

Comment: Yes, it changes the order of the elements, the order doesn't matter to `set`s.

Comment: I don't understand why you return the sequence after yielding all items

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `set` to keep track of the items you have yielded and thus keep the items' order, like below:

```
def unique(sequence):
    yielded = set()
    for i in sequence:
        if i in yielded:
            continue
        yield (i)
        yielded.add(i)
```

Sample output from given input:

```
>>> for x in unique([3,4,5,7,3,9,0,3]):
    print(x)


3
4
5
7
9
0
>>>
```

Comment: `Thank you all for the best input, i have made it work with this.

Comment: Glad to help, if it answers your question mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list(set(sequence))
```

This doesn't do any iteration

Comment: to be pedantic, it doesn't yield the elements because it builds a list.

Comment: how to do make sure i get them in same order ?

Comment: @Wabs Josh: you could probably import unique_everseen from more_itertools...so like this: from more_itertools import unique_everseen, if that doesn't work, you can actually do a pip install more_itertools, and then instead of using a set you could do return list(unique_everseen(sequence)) ===> [3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 0]